# Error saving all valid forms from a formset in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I have a formset but I can only save the last form:

my view:

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def CCView(request):
    newAdFormSet = formset_factory(CodigoCortoForm)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = newAdFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if formset.is_valid():
           for form in formset.forms:
               if form.is_valid():
                  form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
    else:
        formset = newAdFormSet()
    return render_to_response("codcorto.html",
                              {'form':formset},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Th view only inert the last form and i get the error

> Cannot insert NULL into
>   ("PROVEEDORES_CONTENIDO"."PC_CODIGO_CORTO"."ID_PROVEEDOR")

I am using javascript to create more forms in the template with this script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Code adapted from http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1389/
    function updateElementIndex(el, prefix, ndx) {
        var id_regex = new RegExp('(' + prefix + '-\\d+-)');
        var replacement = prefix + '-' + ndx + '-';
        if ($(el).attr("for")) $(el).attr("for", $(el).attr("for").replace(id_regex,
        replacement));
        if (el.id) el.id = el.id.replace(id_regex, replacement);
        if (el.name) el.name = el.name.replace(id_regex, replacement);
    }

    function deleteForm(btn, prefix) {
        var formCount = parseInt($('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val());
        if (formCount > 1) {
            // Delete the item/form
            $(btn).parents('.item').remove();
            var forms = $('.item'); // Get all the forms
            // Update the total number of forms (1 less than before)
            $('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val(forms.length);
            var i = 0;
            // Go through the forms and set their indices, names and IDs
            for (formCount = forms.length; i < formCount; i++) {
                $(forms.get(i)).children().children().each(function () {
                    if ($(this).attr('type') == 'text') updateElementIndex(this, prefix, i);
                });
            }
        } // End if
        else {
            alert("You have to enter at least one todo item!");
        }
        return false;
    }

    function addForm(btn, prefix) {
        var formCount = parseInt($('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val());
        // You can only submit a maximum of 10 todo items
        if (formCount < 51) {
            // Clone a form (without event handlers) from the first form
            var row = $(".item:first").clone(false).get(0);
            // Insert it after the last form
            $(row).removeAttr('id').hide().insertAfter(".item:last").slideDown(300);

            // Remove the bits we don't want in the new row/form
            // e.g. error messages
            $(".errorlist", row).remove();
            $(row).children().removeClass("error");

            // Relabel or rename all the relevant bits
            $(row).children().children().each(function () {
                updateElementIndex(this, prefix, formCount);
                $(this).val("");
            });
            // Add an event handler for the delete item/form link
            $(row).find(".delete").click(function () {
                return deleteForm(this, prefix);
            });
            // Update the total form count
            $("#id_" + prefix + "-TOTAL_FORMS").val(formCount + 1);
        } // End if
        else {
            alert("Sorry, you can only enter a maximum of ten items.");
        }
        return false;
    }
    // Register the click event handlers
    $("#add").click(function () {
        return addForm(this, "form");
    });

    $(".delete").click(function () {
        return deleteForm(this, "form");
    });
});
```

Any advice how to handle this error or what is the proper way to save all the valid forms from a formset.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this snippet

```
function cloneMore(selector, type) {
    var newElement = $(selector).clone(true);
    var total = $('#id_' + type + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
    newElement.find(':input').each(function() {
        var name = $(this).attr('name').replace('-' + (total-1) + '-','-' + total + '-');
        var id = 'id_' + name;
        $(this).attr({'name': name, 'id': id}).val('').removeAttr('checked');
    });
    newElement.find('label').each(function() {
        var newFor = $(this).attr('for').replace('-' + (total-1) + '-','-' + total + '-');
        $(this).attr('for', newFor);
    });
    total++;
    $('#id_' + type + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val(total);
    $(selector).after(newElement);
}
```